# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los números del () de un string?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Hola todos estoy intentado extraer solo los números que están dentro de paréntesis () pero solo he podido obtener los que están fuera, alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

```
str = "h (3110), 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog (500)"
[int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

Saludos, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué hay que hacer con `444.4` ? ¿Lo consideramos como número? Pregunto, por que estas convirtiendo luego a un entero.

Comment: que tal?, solo es los numero en paréntesis, son siempre enteros, pero me gustaría añadir la letra o nombre anterior ejemplo [h,3110; dog, 500], es posible?

Comment: Hola Geology, en mi respuesta asumo que siempre es un entero, si hay la posibilidad de que contenga decimales hay que modificar la expresión. En cuanto a la palabra antes del número, he editado la respuesta, mira al final a ver si te resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasa porque al aplicar `split` (por defecto separa por espacios en blanco), las dos subcadenas con los números con paréntesis quedan como `"(3110),"` y `"(500)"`, en ningún caso se cumple que todos sus caracteres sean dígitos, que el lo que `str.isdigit` comprueba, por lo que el condicional no se cumple.

Posiblemente sería más simple que usaras una expresión regular:

```
import re

cad = "h (3110), 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog (500)"
nums = [int(match.group(1)) for match in re.finditer(r"\((\d+)\)", cad)]
```

> ```
> >>> nums
> [3110, 500]
> ```

La expresión no tiene mucho que explicar:

- **`\(`** -> Literal para "("
- **`(`** -> Inicio del grupo de captura

  - **`\d`** -> clase de caracteres, todos los dígitos, del 0 al 9.
- **`)`** -> fin del grupo de captura.
- **`+`** -> cuantificador, entre una y un número ilimitado de veces. Ambicioso.
- **`\)`** -> literal para ")".

Si quieres obtener también la palabra anterior al número, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import re

cad = "h (3110), 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog (500)"
nums = [[match.group(1), int(match.group(2))]
        for match in re.finditer(r"(\S+)?\s?\S*\((\d+)\)", cad)
        ]
```

> ```
> >>> nums
> [['h', 3110], ['dog', 500]]
> ```

En éste caso usamos dos grupos de captura. `\S`  buscará cualquier carácter que no sea un espacio en blanco (`[\r\n\t\f\v ]`). `\s` justo lo contrario.

Comment: muchas gracias, FJSevilla